# What is an Exokernel?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

Aao!!

I'm currently learning how to create my own OS and am choosing which kernel to go for. I have heard of Monolithic Kernels, Microkernels, Hybrid Kernels, Nano Kernels and Exokernels.

The thing is, I don't understand what Wikipedia has on Nano and Exokernels.
Can someone please explain to me (in English) what the difference between these two kernels to something like a Monolith kernel?

Thanks in advance,
DreddTrekkiter

Comment: Seriously...  If you're planning on creating your own OS, and don't know what the different types of kernels are, you are really in trouble.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: exokernels are concepts in which abstractions are moved in user space so applications have more freedom and security. e.g. instead of inflating the  kernel, file system is implemented in user space while security in "kernel space"